# Issue in my proof that the limit of circles through three points on a curve is the osculating circle

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, curves, curvature, osculating-circle

I'm going through some differential geometry exercises (from Kristopher Tapp's *Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces*) I worked on a while ago, and realised I missed a detail in Part (2) of the following:

> Let $\boldsymbol\gamma: I \to \mathbb R^n$ be a unit-speed curve. Let $t_0 \in I$ and $\kappa(t_0) \neq 0$. For sufficiently small $h > 0$, prove that the three points $\boldsymbol\gamma(t_0 - h), \boldsymbol\gamma(t_0)$, and $\boldsymbol\gamma(t_0 + h)$ are not collinear, so there is a unique plane $P_h$ containing them and a unique circle $C_h$ containing them. Precisely formulate and prove the following:
>
> (1) As $h \to 0$, $P_h$ converges to the osculating plane (translated to $\boldsymbol\gamma(t_0)$).
>
> (2) As $h \to 0$, $C_h$ converges to the osculating circle (translated to $\boldsymbol\epsilon(t_0)$).
>
> *HINT: For (1), use the Taylor approximation formulas from this section. For (2), for fixed $h$, let $\mathbf p(h)$ denote the center of $C_h$, and define
> $$f(s) = \lvert\boldsymbol\gamma(t_0 + s) - \mathbf p(h)\rvert^2.$$
> Since $f(-h) = f(0) = f(h)$, the mean value theorem says that there exist $\delta_1 \in (-h, 0)$ and $\delta_2 \in (0, h)$ with $f'(\delta_1) = f'(\delta_2) = 0$, and then that there exists $\epsilon \in (\delta_1, \delta_2)$ with $f''(\epsilon) = 0$, which becomes
> \begin{align}
> 0 = f'(\delta_i)  &= 2 \langle\boldsymbol\gamma'(t_0 + \delta_i), \boldsymbol\gamma(t_0 + \delta_i) - \mathbf p(h)\rangle \textit{ (for $i \in \{1, 2\}$),}\\
> 0 = f''(\epsilon) &= 2 \langle\boldsymbol\gamma''(t_0 + \epsilon), \boldsymbol\gamma(t_0 + \epsilon) - \mathbf p(h)\rangle + 2 \lvert\boldsymbol\gamma'(t_0 + \epsilon)\rvert^2.
> \end{align}
> Now consider the limit as $h \to 0$.*

In the exercise, $\kappa$ is the curvature function and $\boldsymbol\epsilon$ the center of the osculating circle. Further, the text treats all curves as smooth.

I interpreted the statement as saying that (in addition to the statement in Part (1)) $\lim_{h \to 0^+}\mathbf p(h) = \boldsymbol\epsilon(t_0)$. What I actually showed, however, was that *if* $\lim_{h \to 0^+}\mathbf p(h) = \mathbf L$, then $\mathbf L = \boldsymbol\epsilon(t_0)$:

We define
$$f(s) = \lvert\boldsymbol\gamma(t_0 + s) - \mathbf p(h)\rvert^2.$$
Since $f$ is smooth and $f(-h) = f(0) = f(h)$, the mean value theorem says that there exist $\delta_1 \in (-h, 0)$ and $\delta_2 \in (0, h)$ with $f'(\delta_1) = f'(\delta_2) = 0$, and then that there exists $\epsilon \in (\delta_1, \delta_2)$ with $f''(\epsilon) = 0$, which becomes
\begin{align}
\langle\boldsymbol\gamma'(t_0 + \delta_i), \boldsymbol\gamma(t_0 + \delta_i) - \mathbf p(h)\rangle &= 0\\
\langle\boldsymbol\gamma''(t_0 + \epsilon), \boldsymbol\gamma(t_0 + \epsilon) - \mathbf p(h)\rangle &= -1.
\end{align}
Now, as $h \to 0$, $\delta_i, \epsilon \to 0$, and so if $\lim_{h \to 0^+}\mathbf p(h) = \mathbf L$,
\begin{align}
\langle\boldsymbol\gamma'(t_0), \boldsymbol\gamma(t_0) - \mathbf L\rangle  &= 0\\
\langle\boldsymbol\gamma''(t_0), \boldsymbol\gamma(t_0) - \mathbf L\rangle &= -1.
\end{align}
This tells us that $\mathbf L - \boldsymbol\gamma(t_0) \perp \boldsymbol\gamma'(t_0)$. Further, since $\mathbf p(h)$ lies in $P_h$, $\mathbf L$ lies in the translated osculating plane, and so $\mathbf L - \boldsymbol\gamma(t_0)$ lies in the osculating plane. Thus, $\mathbf L - \boldsymbol\gamma(t_0) \parallel \boldsymbol\gamma''(t_0)$. We can then conclude that $\mathbf L - \boldsymbol\gamma(t_0)$ points in the direction of $\boldsymbol\gamma''(t_0)$ and that $\lvert\mathbf L - \boldsymbol\gamma(t_0)\rvert = \frac{1} {\kappa(t_0)}$, i.e. $\mathbf L - \boldsymbol\gamma(t_0) = \frac{1} {\kappa(t_0)} \mathfrak n$ (where $\mathfrak n$ is the unit normal vector). Thus $\mathbf L = \boldsymbol\epsilon(t_0)$.

However, this doesn't rule out the possibility that $\mathbf p(h)$ doesn't have a limit as $h \to 0$. I thought to try and finish the proof I should show that $\mathbf p$ is smooth with bounded derivative, and hence uniformly continuous. In doing so, however, I found $\mathbf p(h) - \boldsymbol\gamma(t_0)$ in terms of $\mathbf u_1(h) := \boldsymbol\gamma(t_0 + h) - \boldsymbol\gamma(t_0)$ and $\mathbf u_2(h) := \boldsymbol\gamma(t_0 - h) - \boldsymbol\gamma(t_0)$, and a direct calculation of the limit seems to suggest that the limit is $\boldsymbol\gamma(t_0)$ instead.

To find $\mathbf p(h) - \boldsymbol\gamma(t_0)$, I set $\mathbf p(h) - \boldsymbol\gamma(t_0) = \alpha(h) \mathbf u_1(h) + \beta(h) \mathbf u_2(h)$. I then used the condition that $\langle\mathbf p(h) - \boldsymbol\gamma(t_0 + h), \mathbf p(h) - \boldsymbol\gamma(t_0 + h)\rangle = \langle\mathbf p(h) - \boldsymbol\gamma(t_0), \mathbf p(h) - \boldsymbol\gamma(t_0)\rangle = \langle\mathbf p(h) - \boldsymbol\gamma(t_0 - h), \mathbf p(h) - \boldsymbol\gamma(t_0 - h)\rangle$ along with the facts that $\mathbf p(h) - \boldsymbol\gamma(t_0 + h) = (\alpha(h) - 1) \mathbf u_1(h) + \beta(h) \mathbf u_2(h)$ and $\mathbf p(h) - \boldsymbol\gamma(t_0 - h) = \alpha(h) \mathbf u_1(h) + (\beta(h) - 1) \mathbf u_2(h)$ to solve for $\alpha(h), \beta(h)$. As a result, I found
$$\mathbf p(h) - \boldsymbol\gamma(t_0) = \frac{\lvert\mathbf u_2(h)\rvert^2 \langle\mathbf u_1(h), \mathbf u_1(h) - \mathbf u_2(h)\rangle \mathbf u_1(h) + \lvert\mathbf u_1(h)\rvert^2 \langle\mathbf u_2(h) - \mathbf u_1(h), \mathbf u_2(h)\rangle \mathbf u_2(h)}{2 (\lvert\mathbf u_1(h)\rvert^2 \lvert\mathbf u_2(h)\rvert^2 - \langle\mathbf u_1(h), \mathbf u_2(h)\rangle^2)}.$$
But, since $\lim_{h \to 0^+}\mathbf u_1(h) / h = \boldsymbol\gamma'(t_0)$ and $\lim_{h \to 0^+}\mathbf u_2(h) / h = -\boldsymbol\gamma'(t_0)$, this should imply that
$$\lim_{h \to 0^+}(\mathbf p(h) - \boldsymbol\gamma(t_0)) = \lim_{h \to 0^+}\frac{\left\lvert\frac{\mathbf u_2(h)}{h}\right\rvert^2 \left\langle\frac{\mathbf u_1(h)}{h}, \mathbf u_1(h) - \mathbf u_2(h)\right\rangle \frac{\mathbf u_1(h)}{h} + \left\lvert\frac{\mathbf u_1(h)}{h}\right\rvert^2 \left\langle\mathbf u_2(h) - \mathbf u_1(h), \frac{\mathbf u_2(h)}{h}\right\rangle \frac{\mathbf u_2(h)}{h}}{2 \left(\left\lvert\frac{\mathbf u_1(h)}{h}\right\rvert^2 \left\lvert\frac{\mathbf u_2(h)}{h}\right\rvert^2 - \left\langle\frac{\mathbf u_1(h)}{h}, \frac{\mathbf u_2(h)}{h}\right\rangle^2\right)} = \mathbf0.$$
Am I going wrong somewhere?

Comment: First, I don't think the "translated to $\epsilon(t_0)$" belongs there. The mean value theorem argument shows that $f(s)=\lim_{h\to 0} f_h(s)$ vanishes to second order at $0$. Is it not clear that $f(s) = \|\alpha(s)-C\|^2 - R^2$ for some $C$ in the osculating plane (which for computation's sake you should take to be the $xy$-plane)? Of course, $R=\|C\|$ here.

Comment: @TedShifrin The "translated to $\boldsymbol\epsilon(t_0)$" is there because the book defines the osculating circle to be centred at the origin. Perhaps I'm not fully understanding the mean value theorem argument, then. Could you write an answer properly explaining the argument? I can write out the details of the argument as I made it, if it helps. And I am still interested in knowing where my direct calculation is going wrong, even if the mean value theorem argument works on its own.